# how to: save image data to gallery [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 1 question:
I use a library and it returns the Image data type, so how do I save or share the image in the library of my device?

code:

```
 Image image = await HmsScanUtils.buildBitmap(request);
```

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: Image image = (await HmsScanUtils.buildBitmap(request));.

Comment: my data like that, how to save it to the gallery. thank

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

This plugin saves images and videos to gallery/photos.

You need to provide a path to the file that you want to save like below:

```
GallerySaver.saveImage(path)
```

Comment: Image image = (await HmsScanUtils.buildBitmap(request));.  my data like that, how to save it to the library. thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package
`https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver`.
If you dont understand any documentation given on this page then you can simply follow the following tutorial by Johannes

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JILcQLZvjKE
```

Comment: Image image = (await HmsScanUtils.buildBitmap(request));. my data like that, how to save it to the library. thank